# How to retrieve data from Firestore sub collection?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get data from Users and then other collection Reservations. How can I make snapshot for sub collection?

```
Reservations = []
Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
    if let e = error {
        print(e)
    }
        else
        {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents
            {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments
                {
                    let data = doc.data()
                 //   let rid = doc.documentID
                    if let Time = data["Time"] as? String, let Date = data["Date"] as? String, let Guests = data["Guests"] as? String, let RestaurantName = data["RestaurantName"] as? String, let Name = data["Name"] as? String, let Status = data["Status"] as? String, let Phone = data["Phone"] as? String
                    {
                        let newReservation = Reservation(restaurantName: RestaurantName, name: Name, phone: Phone, guests: Guests, time: Time, date: Date, status: Status)
                        self.Reservations.append(newReservation)
             
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print(self.Reservations)
                            self.reservationsTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase Structure]

Comment: So you want to get the user data and reservation data in a single go?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the reservations for the current user in your loop, you can do that with:

```
for doc in snapshotDocuments {
    let reservationsRef = doc.collection("Reservations")
    reservationsRef.getDocuments { (reservationsSnapshot, error) in
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to get all `Reservations` across the entire database in one go, you'll want to have a look at [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).